# Использование переменной снаружи IBaction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть переменная.

```
var variant: Int=0
```

Есть функции, которые должны менять значение после нажатии определенных кнопок.

```
@IBAction func pohudenie(_ sender: Any) {
    variant = 1
    print(variant)
}
@IBAction func podderzhanie(_ sender: Any) {
   variant = 2
    print(variant)
}

@IBAction func nabor(_ sender: Any) {
   variant = 3
    print(variant)
}
```

После этого идет следующая кнопка, в которой должна определяться переменная через if statement и выполнять одно из действий.

```
@IBAction func result(_ sender: Any) {
if  variant == 1  {
        kall2=(kall-(kall/100)*25)
    }
    if variant == 2  {
        kall2=(kall-(kall/100)*20)
    }
    else{
        kall2=kall
    }
}
```

Я опустил лишний код. Проблема в том, что в функции result переменная variant то ли не определяется, то ли в первых трех функциях не меняется переменная на нужную. В результате выполняется третье действие из else. Как решить эту проблему?

Как я понимаю, это изменение переменной остаётся в пределах тех кнопок.

Добавляю весь код

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sextype: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var traning: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var activ: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var resultlabel: UILabel!

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

    var variant: Int = 0;
@IBAction func pohudenie(_ sender: Any) {
    variant = 1
    print(variant)
}
@IBAction func podderzhanie(_ sender: Any) {
        variant = 2
    print(variant)
}

@IBAction func nabor(_ sender: Any) {
   variant = 3
    print(variant)
}

let height = 170
@IBAction func result(_ sender: Any) {
    var kall: Double=0
    var kall2: Double=0
    let activity = [1.2, 1.38, 1.56, 1.73, 1.95]
    let selectedActiv = activity[activ.selectedSegmentIndex]
    let factor = [0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.03, 1.06, 1.09, 1.11, 1.13]
    let selectedFactor = factor[traning.selectedSegmentIndex]
    if let age = Int(text1.text!) {

        if let weight = Int(text2.text!) {

            switch sextype.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                kall=(Double(selectedFactor) * (Double(selectedActiv) * (66 + (13.7 * Double(weight)) + (5 * Double(height)) - (6.8 * Double(age)))))
            case 1:
                kall=(Double(selectedFactor) * (Double(selectedActiv) * (665 + (9.6 * Double(weight)) + (1.8 * Double(height)) - (4.7 * Double(age)))))
            default:
                kall = 0
            }

        }

    }
    switch variant {
        case 1:
        kall2=(kall-(kall/100)*25)
        case 2:
        kall2=(kall-(kall/100)*20)
        case 3:
        kall2=kall
        default:
        kall2=kall
    }

    let belki = 0.31
    let zhir = 0.12
    let uglevod = 0.57
    let belki1 = 3.8
    let zhir1 = 9.3
    let uglevod1 = 4.1
    var belki2: Double=0
    var zhir2: Double=0
    var uglevod2: Double=0

    belki2=(kall2*belki)/belki1
    zhir2=(kall2*zhir)/zhir1
    uglevod2=(kall2*uglevod)/uglevod1

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.endEditing(true)
    resultlabel.text = "Вы должны потреблять \(Int(kall2)) килокалорий\nИз которых: \nБелков:  \(Int(belki2)) g \nЖиров: \(Int(zhir2)) g \nБелков:  \(Int(uglevod2)) g"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в Вашей проверке. Прочитайте ход:

```
if  variant == 1  {
    kall2=(kall-(kall/100)*25)
}
if variant == 2  {
    kall2=(kall-(kall/100)*20)
}
else{
    kall2=kall
}
```

если variant равен 1 - выполняем действие. Если variant равен 2 - выполняем действие, иначе (если variant равен любому числу, кроме 2) выполняем действие. Т.е. kall2=kall отработает всегда, кроме `variant == 2`

Смените на что-то вроде:

```
switch variant {
case 1:
    //одно действие
case 2:
    //второе
case 3:
    //третье
default:
    //все остальное
}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант, все ещё не получается, а если поставить один из case равное нулю, то он выполнит действие. Из этого я делаю вывод, что variant в любом из случаев у меня остается равен 0.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась переносом переменной variant за класс. Моя ошибка была в том, что я не предоставил вам сразу весь код, в котором видно, что переменная находится внутри класса.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть проблема в переменной kall или kall2? Проверьте подключение кнопок, может какие-то открепились.
Просто из того что вы показали вообще не ясно в чем может быть проблема.
Вроде у вас определено всё правильно и изменяется, по этому пояснения были бы очень кстати.

Comment: добавил код выше, переменные kall и kall2 никаких проблем не доставляют)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй самый тривиальный способ, к переменной kal добавь observer:

```
{
   didSet {
      debugPrint("KAL CHANGED: \(self.kal)")
   }
}
```

И по результатам смотри, где именно некорректно изменяет.

Comment: (если обьявляется сразу со значением, то вставь код сразу после обьявления значения, иначе после указания типа переменной (Int и тд))